# I cant get rid of this camera that was set to my armature

Tags: armature, camera

I set a camera to my armature by pressing ctrl + b and now in my timeline there Is a camera icon with the words armature next to it. I can't get rid of it and whenever I set another camera as the primary camera, it gets set back to the armature camera
[image]

Comment: I solved it myself, it was a marker with the camera set to it

Comment: I solved it myself, it was a marker with the camera set to it